# Null pointer exception on iOS when switching forms while editing

Tags: codenameone

It's been a week that I run in a Null Pointer Exception only on iOS builds. Nothing appens on Android and on the Simulator.

It appens only when I am editing a TextField and click on a button to switch to another form or click/swipe to expand the sidemenu.

We upgraded to the pro version in order to get the stackTrace, and we got this :

```
[EDT] 0:0:11,620 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com_codename1_ui_Display.invokeAndBlock:1209
at com_codename1_ui_Display.invokeAndBlock:1223
at com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSImplementation.editString:810
at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneImplementation.editStringImpl:309
at com_codename1_ui_Display.editString:1503
at com_codename1_ui_Display.editString:1471
at com_codename1_ui_TextArea_2.run:1750
at com_codename1_ui_Display.processSerialCalls:1129
at com_codename1_ui_Display.edtLoopImpl:1073
at com_codename1_ui_Display.mainEDTLoop:961
at com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper.run:120
at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176
at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153
```

The main case of occurrences is a Textfield used to search in a infinite container, and we have this structure everywhere in the app since it's an ERP.

Is it a way to get rid of this ? Popping NPE in our production app is obviously a bad thing.
The pro version and the bindCrashProtection set to true prevent showing of the NPE, but we don't know if it will cause bad behavior, it's an EDT Exception after all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is causing this exactly, and I can't seem to reproduce it so far.  Here is the test case I'm working with. If you have a test case that can reproduce the issue, please provide it.  Otherwise, please modify this test case so that it fails.

`private void runTest() {
      Form f = new Form("Test", BoxLayout.y());
      Button b = new Button("Start");
      b.addActionListener(e->{
            showLegacyTestForm();
      });
      f.add(b);
      f.show();
}`

private void showLegacyTestForm() {
        Form hi = new Form("Legacy Test");
        //createToolbar(hi);
        hi.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        Button back = new Button("Back");
        Form prev = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        back.addActionListener(e->{
            if (prev != null) {
                prev.showBack();
            }
        });
        hi.addComponent(back);
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            TextField fi = new TextField("Field " + i);
            hi.addComponent(fi);
        }
        hi.setScrollableY(false);
        hi.show();
    }

(The idea of the test case, is you click the "Start" button to bring you to a form with a bunch of Text fields.  Start editing a field, then press "Back". It should bring you back to the first form.  This is roughly the workflow that you described.